# javascript call() function this context

Tags: javascript

In the following code,

```
var toString = Object.prototype.toString;

toString.call(new Date); // [object Date]
toString.call(new String); // [object String]
toString.call(Math); // [object Math]
```

in the call  the current object is passed like ( `toString.call(new Date)`) , but in the receving end  `var toString = Object.prototype.toString;` here instead of using `this` keyword they are using `Object` keyword but still got the correct answer i didn't understand this concept.Anyone pls help me in understanding this concept

Comment: Are you saying the examples above *are* working or *aren't* working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) executes a function with the provided context.  The `var toString = Object.prototype.toString` passes the `Object`'s `toString` function to a variable .. I suppose for easy access.

Then, you can use `toString.call([new context here])` to call the Object's `toString` method with the provided context.  As you can see, this prints out `[object OBJECTNAME]` as a string.

`Object`'s `toString` is different than some others.  For example:

```
(new Date).toString(); // "Tue Feb 26 2013 01:00:17 GMT-0500 (EST)"
(new String).toString(); // ''
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question. But here goes.

`var toString = Object.prototype.toString;`

In this line you are reading the "prototype" property of Object and reading the "toString" property of the prototype. The toString property is a function. You stored this in your variable.

Now when you do this: `toString.call(new Date);`, you take that function from above and are going to apply it on the object returned by "new Date" (i.e. the `this` context for code in toString becomes the object returned by "new Date")

You can think of this as copying a method belonging to an object and applying it on another object.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to understand how the value of `this` changes depending on how a function is invoked.

First up, we have member functions. `Object.prototype.toString` is a member function of `Object.prototype`. You could visualise this simply as:

```
Object.prototype = {
    toString: function() {} // is responsible for converting an object to it's string representation
};
```

When a member function is invoked, the context of `this` refers to the parent object (the instance of `Object`). As builtin JS objects extend `Object`, they are all able to use `.toString()` with varying results:

```
(new Object).toString(); // [object Object]
(new String).toString(); // [object String]
```

It helps to imagine the inner workings of `.toString()`, you'd imagine it might do something like:

```
// ..
return '[object '+ this.constructor.name + ']';
// ..
```

Hopefully you can now imagine how changing the value of `this` in the function will change the object that is being inspected.

When you invoke `Object.prototype.toString` via .call(), you are able to pass a new value to be used as `this`:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(new Date); // [object Date]
```

I highly recommend reading Yehuda Katz' simple explanation of the 3 ways to affect the value of `this` when invoking a function:

http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/